# System information at Startup / ssh connect are gone Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04

I have installed a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 Server yesterday, system is up and running, ssh is enabled (switched passowrd authentication of and connect only by cert)

when I connect by ssh now the system information is gone and it only shows up one line:

```
Last login: Sun Jan  2 17:48:07 2022 from 192.168.178.100
```

I dont know why and how to get the full information back (like this)

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.x.x-xx-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Thu Jun 11 08:07:28 UTC 2020

  System load:             0.07
  Usage of /:              0.6% of 1.79TB
  Memory usage:            4%
  Swap usage:              0%
  Temperature:             37.0 C
  Processes:               206
  Users logged in:         1
  IPv4 address for enp6s0: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  IPv6 address for enp6s0: xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx

0 updates can be installed immediately.
0 of these updates are security updates.


Last login: Thu Jun 11 08:03:47 2020 from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: That's called the Message Of The Day, also known as the `motd`. Read `man -k motd`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Hmm, the answers are very helpfull, but not what I'm looking for. A Workarround could be to execute this command in bashrc `run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/` But I'm not shure why the scripts would not be executed automaticaly?